# Is there a way to center both item s in a Tk Label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a program and I need a image and an entry field. However when I try to put them in the same column it defaults the to the top left no matter the value. I tried column as various values and it either goes to the top left if they are the same or one goes to the center-ish and one is on the left. is there something I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
pg3 = Tk()
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("download.png"))
pg3.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
tk.Label(pg3, image = img1, anchor = "c").grid(row=0, column = 1)
e1 = tk.Entry(pg3)
e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
pg3.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to configure that column 1 uses all the horizontal space using `pg3.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pack`.

`BaseWidget.pack()` automatically centers all your elements.

P.S. If you want to horizontally center a few elements, you can use a `Frame` to grid the elements and then pack the frame.

Another way will be using `pg3.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`. It is an alias of `grid_columnconfigure`.

```py
def grid_columnconfigure(self, index, cnf={}, **kw):
        """Configure column INDEX of a grid.

        Valid resources are minsize (minimum size of the column),
        weight (how much does additional space propagate to this column)
        and pad (how much space to let additionally)."""
```

So you can set the weight to 1 to center it.

Comment: FWIW, `grid` also automatically centers widgets in the space allocated to them.

Comment: You said _allocated_ too. `grid` centers widgets in allocated space but the space is allocated as the largest size of the widgets whereas `pack` allocates the full space. @BryanOakley

Comment: Yes, correct, though `grid` can allocate whole rows or columns just like `pack`.